# It is possible to run R in IIS?

Tags: iis

I know that it is possible to run a "R server" using RApache. Unfortunately, RApache does not run under windows at all. There are some alternative, e.g. Rook oder RSERVE, but both lack in maintenance and features. 
Furthermore, we already have an IIS - so I would like to run R inside IIS. Does somebody now if that is even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you attempting to write a cgi-type app using R? 
or
Are you trying to have a server gui so that folks can run their own code on more beefy hardware? (Like R Studio Server)
I am not sure exactly your goals but...
 Either way I am afraid that the windows support will be lacking. 
R is great about providing windows binaries of the app itself for the community but anything beyond that is very *nix-centric.

Comment: It is more a cgi-type app: Push some data in, get a result back.

I gussed as much - unfortunately the company here is very windows centric...

Comment: If is is really simple stuff I would think that you could hack something together with a dot net app and something like http://jmp75.github.io/rdotnet/ without too much difficulty.